# Facebook Like Button Deprecated Value Showing Up

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm having this weird issue with only the base URL of our forums. I added a like button. When I tested it, the url that was liked showed up as "www.facebook.com/pages/toonzo..." instead of "www.toonzone.net/forums/" or "www.toonzone.net/forums/forum.php". After a lot of digging through the page using Chrome, I found out it was coming from what looks to be deprecated javascript with that URL. Upon looking even closer, it's being called from facebook's like.php file.

My next step, to confirm that this was something involving the URL and facebook and not something else was to create a new like button on facebook using the URL. Sure enough, that incorrect URL showed up there too.

I'm guessing maybe a long time ago, something goofed and it's been stuck like that ever since. Because, the incorrect URL looks like our original fan page address. But, I have no idea at all how to correct this. I tried tossing the URL into the debug tool on the facebook developers site. Here's the javascript snippet and site URL:

http://www.toonzone.net/forums/

```
ServerJSQueue.add({"define":[["XDVerifiedChannel",[],{"channel":"http:\/\/static.ak.facebook.com\/connect\/xd_arbiter.php?version=9#cb=f2891cc4a&origin=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.toonzone.net\u00252Ff1d709ba3&domain=www.toonzone.net&relation=parent.parent"}]]});onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){Bootloader.done([])});onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){defer_until(function() { new ExternalPageLikeWidget({"viewer":1027609353,"channelURL":"http:\/\/static.ak.facebook.com\/connect\/xd_arbiter.php?version=9#cb=f2891cc4a&origin=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.toonzone.net\u00252Ff1d709ba3&domain=www.toonzone.net&relation=parent.parent","mobile":false,"nodeType":"page","externalURL":"http:\/\/www.toonzone.net\/forums\/forum.php","widgetID":"connect_widget_5020888885b1a5865896767","alreadyConnected":false,"viewerIsAdmin":false,"adminUrl":"","showFaces":false,"useUnlikeLink":false,"layout":"box_count","locale":"en_US","commentWidgetMarkup":"\u003Cdiv id=\"uf3jom_1\" style=\"font-family: &quot;arial&quot;, sans-serif\" class=\"connect_comment_widget connect_comment_widget_ltr\" title=\"toonzone forums\">\u003Cdiv class=\"nub\">\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"comment_content\">\u003Cdiv class=\"connect_comment_widget_placeholder_input_region hidden_elem\">\u003Cinput class=\"connect_comment_widget_placeholder_input inputtext\" type=\"text\" value=\"Add a comment\" \/>\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"connect_comment_widget_full_input_region clearfix\">\u003Cdiv>\u003Cimg class=\"-cx-PRIVATE-uiSquareImage__root connect_comment_widget_user_pic -cx-PRIVATE-uiSquareImage__large img\" src=\"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/276075_1027609353_1137351_q.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/>\u003Ctextarea aria-label=\"Add a comment\" class=\"connect_comment_widget_full_input_textarea connect_comment_widget_disabled inputtext\">Add a comment\u003C\/textarea>\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"connect_comment_share_preview\">\u003Ctable class=\"uiGrid\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">\u003Ctbody>\u003Ctr>\u003Ctd class=\"vTop\">\u003Cdiv>\u003Cimg class=\"connect_comment_share_preview_pic img\" src=\"https:\/\/fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQBsqmNXd4pF0tmu&amp;w=50&amp;h=50&amp;url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.toonzone.net\u00252Fimages\u00252Ftz6\u00252FtzLogo.png\" alt=\"\" \/>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/td>\u003Ctd class=\"vTop\">\u003Cdiv style=\"padding-left: 6px; \">\u003Cdiv class=\"connect_comment_widget_title fsl fwb fcb\">toonzone forums\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"mbs connect_comment_widget_href fsm fwn fcg\">http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/pages\/toonzo...\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"mbs connect_comment_widget_description fsm fwn fcg\">Animation news and discussion. toonzone has been providing news, information and community to animation enthusiasts since August 1998.\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/td>\u003C\/tr>\u003C\/tbody>\u003C\/table>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"connect_comment_widget_button_region\">\u003Clabel class=\"connect_comment_widget_post_button uiButton uiButtonConfirm\" for=\"uf3jom_2\">\u003Cinput value=\"Post to Facebook\" type=\"submit\" id=\"uf3jom_2\" \/>\u003C\/label>\u003Clabel class=\"connect_comment_widget_close_button uiButton\" for=\"uf3jom_3\">\u003Cinput value=\"Close\" type=\"submit\" id=\"uf3jom_3\" \/>\u003C\/label>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>","error":null,"autoResize":true,"connectText":0,"socialbar":false,"ref":".UCCIg6eFIhc.like","userOptedOut":false,"showCaptcha":false,"usingInlineCommenting":false,"isBlocked":false,"forceCommentHooks":"","isPersonalized":false,"colorScheme":null,"grayOut":true,"iframeReferer":"http:\/\/www.toonzone.net\/forums\/forum.php"}); },function() { return ge("connect_widget_5020888885b1a5865896767"); })});onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){AsyncLoader.loadCSS("https:\/\/s-static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yV\/r\/wspVKE9hHCT.css");});
```

Comment: I've tested it here and your button is working fine. I think you tested it logged in Facebook as your fanpage, right?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. When I did the test, I was definitely logged in as myself. Just to clarify, it works... I think. But it's definitely showing the wrong URL once it's been liked. You click like, then it pulls up a small overlay and the URL on that is incorrect. I don't know if that affects anything, beyond perhaps being confusing to anyone who happens to notice it. I can give it a shot while logged in as the fan page and see if that affects anything.

Comment: Even that is working fine here. The comment posted to the wall is pointing to http://www.toonzone.net/forums/forum.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested and everything there is working fine. The Facebook's scripts inside the like's iframe is really very obscure. But my my guess is simple: you was logged in as your fanpage during the test. Because of that, your fanpage's URL was showing somewhere in the script, because it would be your fanpage liking and commenting on your webpage, but posting in your fanpage's wall. With a real user, this not going to happen.

Comment: I was definitely logged in as myself. I double-checked, but so long as this isn't adversely affecting anything, then I suppose it's a non-issue. Thanks so much for checking that out. It was very much appreciated.